# MySQL syntax error "near 'describe)"

Tags: mysql

I can't find the error in this query:

```
INSERT INTO realestate ( 
type, offer, seller, area, build_area, price, is_negotiable, fur, floor_num, rooms, baths, year_built, phone, title, describe 
) VALUES ( 
'2', '1', '1', '98', '99887', '3242839', 'true', 'true', '1', '1', '1', '2010', '97854984576', 'lksehjfsed', 'alidjaopdhkljhdfkedfhwekdfhwseldfk' )
```

This is the error message that I get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'describe ) VALUES ( '2', '1', '1', '98', '99887', '324' at line 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write SQL for a table that shares the same name as a protected keyword in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706920/how-can-i-write-sql-for-a-table-that-shares-the-same-name-as-a-protected-keyword)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DESCRIBE` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You need to enclose it in backquotes if you use it as a column  or table name:

```
INSERT INTO realestate ( 
type, ...., floor_num, rooms, baths, year_built, phone, title, `describe` 
) VALUES ( 
'2', '1', '1', '98', '99887', '3242839', 'true', 'true', '1', '1', '1', '2010', '97854984576', 'lksehjfsed', 'alidjaopdhkljhdfkedfhwekdfhwseldfk' )
```

(columns removed from list for readability)...